# Printing a PHP Array from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print all the items in a row from a particular table from a mysql database.

Here is the out put I am getting (which is not what I want):

```
**mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 28 [type] => 0 ) Array ( )**
```

Here is how I am doing it:

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    mysqli_select_db($connect, "TrackTool");

    $fetch1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM SalesForceActions");

    // set array
    $array = array();

    // look through query
    while($row = mysql_query($fetch1)){

        // add each row returned into an array
        $array[] = $row;

    }

    print_r($fetch1);
    print_r($array);

    mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: What do you want to obtain? Each row will be stored in an array.

Comment: why are you mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions? Your `mysqli_` functions are not correct, as it looks like you are using the `mysql_` syntax/parameters, but using the `mysqli_` prefix. see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php for examples of each.

Comment: Something that doesn't pan out here. You say that your database name is `ActionTable`, yet you're trying to connect to `TrackTool`. Then there's `SalesForceActions`. Something I'm not getting?

Comment: @Fred yeah i messed up by forgetting to change it in the code.. whoops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fetch the result after running the query. So you execute the query then loop which fetching from those results

Like so:

```
$fetch1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM SalesForceActions");

$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch1)){
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

You were also mixing mysqli_* functions with mysql_* functions. Be sure to NOT mix those. In fact, just use mysqli_* functions from now on as the mysql_* functions are being deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *fetch* the result using [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) (or equivalent):

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch1)) {
  $array[] = $row;
}
print_r($array);
```

If you indeed want all the rows, take a look [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_all):

```
$array = mysqli_fetch_all($fetch1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: thats returning the same thing.

Comment: so basically it is returning nothing it looks like this: "Array()"

Comment: This is not the full code. Replace the relevant code above. If it's still an empty array, then something else is wrong.

Comment: @Moose Another thing I don't get. This answer is the same as you accepted above, minus `$fetch1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM SalesForceActions");` which you already had (posted) and `mysql_`. Theoretically, this was the first correct answer, or was it the fact that your code didn't work with `mysql_`? *Curious*.

Comment: @Fred, its because the other answer pointed out that i messed up by forgetting the "i" in mysqli_*, therefore it was slightly better an answer in my case. Sorry, I can only choose one answer as correct, not two.

Comment: @Moose I understand. Well, maybe a **+1** could be in order? :) *Just saying*. ;-)